# changing step in the loop T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

Hello.
I have some trouble. I have a table with dates for 4 years. I need to run loop through it using a day value = 7, month value = 30 and years = 365.
How can I change this value inside the loop?

```
WHILE @start_date <= @finish_date
    BEGIN
        -- SOME ALGORITHM
        SET @start_date = @start_date + 1
    END
```

I would like to get changing value @start1 = 7 + 1; @start1 = 30 + 1 and @start1 = 365 + 1.
I think it's possible, but I haven't any idea (haven't any working idea at the moment)

I was trying to use CASE construction, but when I ran it - my DBeaver application was shut down immediately.

Comment: Read about [DATEADD (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dateadd-transact-sql).

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: Ok, I understand you. I use on Ubuntu + mssql-server-linux latest 2017

Comment: Looping through data like this is almost always the wrong approach in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use `DATEADD` with `YEAR/MONTH/DAY`

```
DECLARE @start_date date='20140101'
DECLARE @finish_date date='20160101'

WHILE @start_date <= @finish_date
BEGIN
    PRINT CONVERT(varchar(10),@start_date,120)
    SET @start_date = DATEADD(YEAR,1,@start_date)
    --SET @start_date = DATEADD(MONTH,1,@start_date)
    --SET @start_date = DATEADD(DAY,1,@start_date)
END
```